# Dovecot config file format

Tags: dovecot

I need all dovecot config keywords and default values. There is a [dovecot-example.conf](https://www.dovecot.org/doc/dovecot-example.conf) on dovecot official site.

OS: CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core) 
Dovecot: 2.2.10

But, It has some errors, e.g. in the exmaple config:

```
# If you want to specify ports for each service, you will need to configure
# these settings inside the protocol imap/pop3 { ... } section, so you can
# specify different ports for IMAP/POP3. For example:
#   protocol imap {
#     listen = *:10143
#     ssl_listen = *:10943
#     ..
#   }
#   protocol pop3 {
#     listen = *:10100
#     ..
#   }
```

This returns errors when run *doveconf -n*

```
doveconf: Warning: NOTE: You can get a new clean config file with: doveconf -n > dovecot-new.conf
doveconf: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/20-imap.conf:57: listen=..:port has been replaced by service { inet_listener { port } }
doveconf: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/20-imap.conf:57: protocol { listen } has been replaced by service { inet_listener { address } }
doveconf: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/20-imap.conf:58: ssl_listen=..:port has been replaced by service { inet_listener { port } }
doveconf: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/20-imap.conf:58: protocol { ssl_listen } has been replaced by service { inet_listener { address } }
```

Another thing is that example config has following sections and define all imap related settings in that.

```
protocol imap {
...
}
```

However, on Centos 7, there is a *20-imap.conf* file and all imap related settings are defined globally not within *protocol imap* section.

Which one is better? To place all imap settings in *protocol imap* section or globally like in centos default config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`doveconf -a > fullconfig.txt` will produce exactly what you need. The only exception is the directives like `local` that have no default values and thus will not be mentioned.

In opposite, `doveconf -n > deltas.txt` will produce the list of options their values are differ from defaults.

Comment: Which one is better? To place all imap settings in protocol imap section or globally like in centos default config. e.g. imap_idle_notify_interval defined in protocol imap section also globally in 20-imap.conf. Both are displayed when I run doveconf -a. Which one has priority?

Comment: I prefer monolitic single config file not teared to shreds. Splitted config is useful for GUI-configurators that do not need to parse the whole config for some section. If you edit config by hands, `doveconf -n` is the weapon of choice.